# Custom runner with regex to parse errors

Tags: cloud9-ide

Sublime Text 2/3 supports custom regex for parsing errors from the output of a custom runner. I've just tried using `file_regex` property in a custom runner but it is ignore. Thus it doesn't capture file name, row, col and message. Does Cloud9 IDE support this? Here is my regex for parsing `javac` output:

```
{
  "cmd" : ["/usr/local/bin/mvn", "compile"],
  "env" : {...},
  "info" : "Building $project_path/$file_name",
  "selector": "source.ext",
  "working_dir": "$project_path",
  "file_regex": "^\\[ERROR\\] (.*\\/\\w+\\.java):\\[(\\d+),(\\d+)\\]([\\s\\S]*?)$"
}
```

When I hit `goToNextError` key, a popup says "Looks good!"

Original regex without `\\` escapes:

```
^\[ERROR\] (.*\/\w+\.java):\[(\d+),(\d+)\]([\s\S]*?)$
```

EDIT: This happened to be a limitation on `cloud9`'s side back at the time.